# How to prevent Tooltip content reading in JAWS reader

Tags: tooltip, jaws-screen-reader

I am using Tooltip for multiple input elements and showing the Tooltip on input elements both hovering and clicking. I need to prevent the JAWS reader from reading the Tooltip content while hovering. I have tried to remove the "role" attribute and set the "aria-hidden" attribute as true.

But none of this way works and the Tooltip still readable. Any assistance would be appreciable. we are using JAWS 2020.2008.24 ILM

Answer (score 0):

There could be several things at play here.  The first is that JAWS, by default, does **not** announce anything when you move the mouse so I'm puzzled why you are hearing something read when you hover.  There's a "mouse echo" setting in the JAWS Setting Center but that's off by default for JAWS (unless you're running ZoomText).  Did you specifically turn that feature on?

Secondly, you say you are **showing** the tooltip. So you're not relying on the default tooltip feature of browsers via the `title` attribute?  You are handling the tooltip yourself and displaying it via javascript?  JAWS will not announce newly displayed text **unless** the new text is in an `aria-live` region.  Are you using live regions?

And lastly, if a tooltip attribute is being used, such as the `title` attribute, then the tooltip text *might* be used in the [accessible name calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2) or in the accessible description.  It's the last attribute looked at (step 2.I).  If it's being used in that manner, then you would **not** want to turn that off.  It's expected behavior by JAWS users.

You may want to post some code to clarify all these issues in order to get a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is mainly happening because of the parent have a `aria-describedby` attribute which leads to hover tag being read by JAWS reader even if it has `aria-hidden` attribute set to `true` as mentioned in this article from ADG [here](https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/sensible-aria-usage/hidden/#not-hidden-anymore-as-description).

`Elements hidden using aria-hidden are not hidden anymore when referencing them using aria-describedby.`

The solution for that is by setting `aria-describedby` to `void 0` as shown in the code below

```
<Tooltip
  aria-describedby={void 0}
  PopperProps={{
    'aria-hidden': true
  }}
>
  <div>Hover here!</div>
</Tooltip>
```